# What is the difference between file_get_contents and $_REQUEST when we receive api data

Tags: php

I am trying to read api data from another source. Here several times when I have used `file_get_contents('php://input');` I got all data.Today in a new api request when I have used `file_get_contents('php://input');` data is not receiving. In this time I used

```
$inputJSON  =  $_REQUEST;
```

Now it's working. Now My question is,what's the difference between

```
$inputJSON  =  file_get_contents('php://input');  
$inputJSON  =  $_REQUEST;
```

Comment: I guess the php docs explain this: request can be post get an cookie data. Input is the raw post data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` — Reads entire file into a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

`$_REQUEST` — Reads HTTP Request variables

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

So for example you have a `sample.txt` file with some contents inside it. `file_get_contents` will read the entire file and display the result.

Where as `$_REQUEST` will just read the `HTTP` request variables that are sent through a form `post` or `get` method.

Comment: If I use file_get_contents , will I get HTTP request variable ?

Comment: No it will read the file contents purely. `HTTP variables` are available through `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` methods with each having their own properties.